# Get all permissions for logged in user,EPiServer

Tags: episerver

I have a custom property which I want to render differently depending on the users permissions.. my problem is that I dont quite know how to get the permissions for the logged in user.. and as mentioned my "context" is not inside a page, its in custom property..

How would I get the permissions for the current user?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

If you're not looking for permissions for a specific page you can use things such as:

```
EPiServer.Security.PrincipalInfo.HasAdminAccess
```

However, that's for the CMS as a whole, not for a specific page.

Also, you can always get the current page even if you're in a static context: http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Mari-Jorgensen/Dates/2008/4/Accessing-CurrentPage-from-a-static-context/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Access Control List](http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms6/html/T_EPiServer_Security_AccessControlList.htm) class.

```
if (CurrentPage.ACL.QueryDistinctAccess(EPiServer.Security.AccessLevel.Create))
{
    // Checks whether the currently logged-on user has
    // Create permission for the current page.
}
```

Comment: the problem is that since its in the context of a custom property where I want to check the logged in users permissions, CurrentPage doesnt exist.. if I have understod it all right..

Comment: If you inherit from PropertyString you will have CurrentPage.